# Psalm stdClass with properties definition anotation error

Tags: php, annotations, psalm-php

What is the correct returning object definition in psalm?

```
/** 
 * @psalm-return \stdClass{foo?: string}
 */
function returnObject(): \stdClass {
 $item2 = new \stdClass();
 $item2->foo = "asd";
    return $item2;
}

returnObject();

ERROR: InvalidDocblock - 19:1 - Unexpected brace character in docblock for returnObject
```

[sandbox](https://psalm.dev/r/74a2b6aaf5)

Answer (score 1):

[You can do this with `object`](https://psalm.dev/r/91d1fd94b5), but you can't do this with any named class, including `stdClass`:

```php
<?php
/** 
 * @psalm-return object{foo?: string}
 */
function returnObject(): object {
    $item2 = new stdClass();
    $item2->foo = "asd";
    return $item2;
}

$_v = returnObject();
/** @psalm-trace $_v */;
```

```
Psalm output (using commit 73ebe22): 

INFO: Trace - 12:24 - $_v: object{foo?:string}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using is not supported:

```
/** 
 * @psalm-return \stdClass{foo?: string}
 */
```

You should only indicate the type, followed by an optional description:

```
/** 
 * @psalm-return \stdClass Returns an object with the foo property set.
 */
```

Comment: So do you mean that I can't specify object fields description using stdClass as a return type inside psalm annotations?

Comment: @Vixtrime Where did you see in Psalm documentation that you could use such a syntax?